# Byobu output only updates through window switch

Tags: ssh, byobu

I am having an issue with Byobu over SSH. When I type in something or do any input, my cursor doesn't move and the screen doesn't update. However when I toggle windows (f4 then f3) it shows the most recent output and cursor position.

What causes this problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you using `tmux` or `screen` as backend? Which versions of Ubuntu & byobu are you using _(client and target machine)_? Are you using nested byobu sessions _(from an open byobu session connecting to a machine running byobu too)_?

Comment: Byobu is tmux and screen combined. I don't understand what you mean by that. Anyway, I'm using the latest byobu on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and I don't do nested byobu sessions.

Comment: Byobu uses `tmux` _or_ `screen` as backend to do the multiplexing. If `tmux` is installed on your system, it defaults to use it instead of screen. Have you modified config files or something similar? What notifications do you have enabled?

Comment: When I use `tmux`, it shows `sessions should be nested with care, unset $TMUX to force`, meaning byobu is using tmux.

Comment: I have the identical problem right now; by gum I wish you'd found the solution. FWIW, the problem seems to self-resolve after several minutes (without restarting Byobu/SSH session), so my current fix is patience.

Comment: @ropable have you tried restarting byobu? Are any of your applications creating weird escape sequences that confuse tmux?

Comment: @Dev Yes, restarting Byobu resolves the problem. But then I lose all my in-progress tabs & tasks.

Comment: @ropable have you tried the `reset` command?

Comment: @Dev I haven't tried the `reset` command, and a cursory search doesn't reveal how I might do so

Comment: @ropable by pressing F2 to open a new window, typing `reset`, and pressing Enter. It's exactly the same way you'd run any other command.

Comment: @Dev Ahah, I'd assumed that `reset` was something Byobu-specific. Didn't solve my problem, though :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed that restarting byobu (by quitting all the processes inside it) worked. I don't know what causes this however, so if somebody would like to shed some light on that please do.

Edit: The issue appeared again after messing with stdout using python, maybe that is the issue?

Comment: Ok, is weird, byobu is pretty straightforward. I have the same _(default)_ config on all my hosts and is working ok. Maybe try to purge and reinstall _on the target host_ with `sudo apt purge byobu && sudo apt install byobu`, try to uninstall `screen` if its installed and you don't use it, or even try another _mainly_ compatible terminal emulator like `lxterminal` to discard elements involved.

Comment: The internet has so much potential but I never get an explanation on *why* something does what it does. All I get is "Oh try reinstalling. If that doesn't work try rebooting or reinstalling."

Comment: ^ no offense. :)

Comment: No problem. I'm telling that cause i've used for years without config like it were a simple tool like a toothpick... Maybe you are connecting from putty? Any special config on tmux? If not I would suggest running `byobu-config` to check actual configuration or even install a new VM or docker container for checking onto a _"fresh install" environment_

Comment: And yes can be realated to messing  with stdout, check if you have any running script/software which can be messing/interfering  with stdout/bash outputing.

Answer (score 1):

reset command seems to resolve this problem. Press F6 to get out of byobu.
Then type "reset" and resumr byobu. It works fine

Answer (score 1):

I found that exiting the Byobu session (F6) and running the `byobu detach` command before running `byobu` again fixes this issue.

Comment: It's `detach`...

Answer (score 1):

For me, simply detaching all other sessions but yourself (Alt + F6) seem to work as well.